# How long before I (see q.) will have recovered the extra purchase cost?

Tags: arithmetic

Standard 100w light bulbs cost 40p each and are expected to last for 2 year in average use. Low power equivalent brightness bulbs cost £10 each, are expected to last 8 years and use only 20W. A 100W light bulb operated for 10 hours will use 7.5p of electricity. A 20w bulb will operate for 50 hours on the same amount of electricity. I have a light in my living room which is on for about 20 hours per week. Next time the living room bulb breaks, I will buy a low wattage build instead of a standard on.

How long will it before i have recovered the extra purchase cost?

70 weeks, 77 weeks, 80 weeks, 83 weeks or 96 weeks?

NB what is the actual purchase cost the 40p/1000p, that's whats confusing me about this calculation? Or is it the relative Watt:price ratio over a given time?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: They give equivalent light, so you just need to compute weeks needed before the difference in electricity charges = difference in cost of bulbs

Comment: got it now thank you, 79.62 weeks, i.e. 80 weeks, being a right idiot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get **exactly** $80$.

Check what you did, probably due to rounding error, over which you need to be very careful, sometimes wrong answers are devilishly close to the right one !

Difference in purchase price $= 1000-40 = 960p$

Current weekly cost $= 15p$

New weekly cost $= \dfrac15\cdot15 = 3p$

Weeks needed to recover extra purchase cost $= \dfrac{960}{15-3}=80$

Comment: lord what is wrong with me, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome !